# LGBMClassifier in RandomizedSearchCV: best_params_ using eval_metric or scoring?

Tags: python, lightgbm

I'm running a grid search with the LGBMClassifier:

```
fit_params={"early_stopping_rounds":30, 
            "eval_metric" : 'auc', 
            "eval_set" : [(X_test_,y_test_)],
            'eval_names': ['valid'],
            'verbose': 100}

param_test ={'num_leaves': sp_randint(6, 50), 
             'min_child_samples': sp_randint(100, 500), 
             'min_child_weight': [1e-5, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 1e1, 1e2, 1e3, 1e4],
             'subsample': sp_uniform(loc=0.2, scale=0.8), 
             'colsample_bytree': sp_uniform(loc=0.4, scale=0.6),
             'reg_alpha': [0, 1e-1, 1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 50, 100],
             'reg_lambda': [0, 1e-1, 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
             'scale_pos_weight':[1,2,6,12]}


n_HP_points_to_test = 100

#n_estimators is set to a "large value". 
# The actual number of trees build will depend on early stopping and 5000 define only the absolute maximum
clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier(max_depth=-1, random_state=314, silent=False, metric='None', n_jobs=-1, n_estimators=5000)

gs = RandomizedSearchCV(
    estimator = clf,
    param_distributions = param_test, 
    n_iter = n_HP_points_to_test,
    scoring = 'balanced_accuracy',
    cv = 3,
    refit = False,
    random_state = 314,
    verbose = 10)

gs.fit(X_train_, y_train_, **fit_params)
print('Best score reached: {} with params: {} '.format(gs.best_score_, gs.best_params_))
```

I would like to optmize in terms of best `balanced_accuracy`, however, I don't understand if the `"eval_metric" : 'auc'` is taken into account in the grid search.

In other words, could you tell me if the `gs.best_params_` will be those best in relation to the `"eval_metric" : 'auc'` or in relation to `scoring = 'balanced_accuracy'`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood the answer to my question.

If I dump the results of `RandomizedSearchCV` in a pandas dataframe:

`pd.DataFrame(gs.cv_results_)`

I get the best solution for the best mean value (calculated over the 3 splits of the CV) of the `balanced_accuracy`.

I believe `eval_metric` would only be used if validation data are provided and is, however, not used in `RandomizedSearchCV`.

Would be good anyway if anybody could confirm my interpretation.